# How does $ 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{(n+2)\sqrt{(n+1)} + (n+1) \sqrt{(n+2)}}$ reduce to $ 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\;$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{(n+2)\sqrt{(n+1)} + (n+1) \sqrt{(n+2)}}$$

Reduces to:

$$ 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}} $$

I have no clue how. What is the exact trick here and how can I practice this? I can't properly google the problem.

Comment: You could rationalize the denominator of the last expression, although it would take some effort. Consider rationalizing it, after factorizing out some common factor from the denominator. If you've made some progress along these lines, then consider editing your post to reflect the progress. Finally, use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) to search for mathematical expressions ; the search results consist of posts on MSE or on the AoPS(Art of Problem Solving)website.

Comment: If you have $\frac{1}{a+b}$ you can rewrite as $\frac{a-b}{a^2-b^2}$ by multiplying top and bottom of the orginal expression by $(a-b)$. This is the standard approach to removing square roots from the denominator. After that, tidy up and re-assess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Here is a different approach for the sake of curiosity (as suggested by Paul in the comments).

Precisely, we shall multiply the numerator and the denominator by the conjugate of the denominator:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(n+2)\sqrt{n+1} + (n+1)\sqrt{n+2}} & = \frac{(n+2)\sqrt{n+1} - (n+1)\sqrt{n+2}}{(n + 2)^{2}(n+1) - (n+1)^{2}(n+2)}\\\\
& = \frac{(n+2)\sqrt{n+1} - (n+1)\sqrt{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, I tried the conjugate trick but the problem was that to keep things tidy I did $n+2 = A$ and $n+1=B$ substitutions and then I didn't see how you could combine the denominator.

Comment: @bananenheld You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

$\require{cancel}$I'd us a combination putting over a common denominator and factoring.

Using that $foo = \sqrt{foo}^2$ we can factor $\sqrt{n+1}$ out of $(n+2)\sqrt{n+1} + (n+1)\sqrt{(n+2)}= \color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}[(n+2) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}]$

So

$1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{(n+2)\sqrt{(n+1)} + (n+1) \sqrt{(n+2)}}=$

$1 -\frac 1{\color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}} + \frac 1{\color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}[(n+2) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}]}=$

$1- \frac {(n+2) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}}{\color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}[(n+2) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}]}+\frac 1{\color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}[(n+2) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}]}=$

$1-\frac {(n+2) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}-1}{\color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}[(n+2) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}]}=$

$1-\frac {(n+1) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}}{\color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}[(n+2) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}]}=$

$1-\frac {\color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n+2})}{\color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}[(n+2) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}]}=$

$1-\frac {\cancel{\color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}}(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n+2})}{\color{green}{\cancel{\color{green}{\sqrt{n+1}}}}[(n+2) + \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}]}=$

$1-\frac {\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}}{(n+2)+\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}}=$

$1 -\frac {\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}}{\color{red}{\sqrt{n+2}}(\sqrt{n+2} + \sqrt{n+1})}=$

$1 -\frac {\cancel{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}}}{\color{red}{\sqrt{n+2}}\cancel{(\sqrt{n+2} + \sqrt{n+1})}}=$

$1 - \frac 1{\color{red}{\sqrt{n+2}}}$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain :)